# Unable to change the settimer value

Tags: c++, winapi

I am using settimer to start the timer. I want to change the timer value everytime the timer lapses.
The code is as below:

```
#include<iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include<WinUser.h>
#pragma comment( lib, "user32.lib" )


    void main()
    {

        int id = 1;
        static bool isStart = false;
        static long l = 10000;
        while(1)
        {
            int n;
            MSG msg = {0};

            {

                SetTimer(NULL, id,l,NULL);

                while(GetMessage(&msg,NULL, 0,0))  
                {
                    // Post WM_TIMER messages to the hwndTimer procedure. 
                    if (msg.message == WM_TIMER) 
                    {
                        std::cout << "Timer expired";
                        KillTimer(NULL, id);
                        msg.message = 0x0;
                        l = 20000;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Even though I change the value to 20000 its not taking, the timer is set only once.
Need help on this.

Thanks

Comment: I guess your messages `msg` aren't getting dispatched to the window. Why not include `DispatchMessage(&msg);` in the `GetMessage` loop?

Also, what is the need of `#include<WinUser.h>` when you have `#include <windows.h>`?

Comment: I used DispatchMessage(&msg); still its not working

Comment: where did you add it?

Comment: after checking for the WM_TIMER(if (msg.message == WM_TIMER) ) in this block

Comment: ok. did you add `TranslateMessage(&msg);` before `DispatchMessage(&msg);` ?

Comment: yes added still not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the return value of SetTimer to kill the timer

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    static bool isStart = false;
    static long l = 5000;
    while(1)
    {
        int n;
        MSG msg = {0};

        UINT_PTR p = SetTimer(NULL, 0,l,NULL);

        while(GetMessage(&msg,NULL, 0,0))
        {
    // Post WM_TIMER messages to the hwndTimer procedure.
            if (msg.message == WM_TIMER)
            {
                std::cout << "Timer expired" << std::endl;
                KillTimer(NULL, p);
                msg.message = 0x0;
                l = 20000;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> SetTimer From MSDN
>
> Return value
>
> Type: Type: UINT_PTR If the function succeeds and the hWnd parameter
>   is NULL, the return value is an integer identifying the new timer. An
>   application can pass this value to the KillTimer function to destroy
>   the timer.

Comment: @Sneha: If an answer fully addresses your problem, you should accept it. This makes it easier for future visitors to quickly find the correct solution.

Comment: @IInspectable I have already replied the answer was useful, and its working now, please see the comment

Comment: what he means is to accept the answer by pressing the 'V' next to the answer so it will be marked as a correct answer on the site

Comment: @Sneha: Please make sure you read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Since you haven't done so, it's probably a good idea to take the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) as well.